# How to use SQL in MVC razor View for table?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I use in my View in MVC this to display table:

```
@foreach (var use in Model)
{
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => use.userID)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => use.username)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => use.Roles)</td>
   <tr>
<tbody>
```

Now column "Roles" is display as number (because it is set as integer in my userTable). But I also have table roleTable, where I have Id and NameOfRole. Now I whant to display NameOfRole from roleTable instead use.Roles.

So far I have try this code:

```
<td>
    @{

        var test = from c in new userDbEntities().roleTables
            where c.Id == use.Roles
            select c.NameOfRole;
        Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test);    
     }
</td>
```

But this is not working.

Any Ideas where is a mistake?

Thanks for help...

Comment: I assume roles is a list of some sort, have you tried use.Roles[0].NameOfRole. This should work, if it does you can just create another loop to show all the roles

Comment: This is bad practice, you have to write those logic inside your controller.

Comment: why is a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Roles is actually navigation property then you should be able to use

```
<td>@String.Join(", ", use.Roles.Select(r => r.NameOfRole))</td>
```

To get all roles as comma separated list.

If you dont include the roles when getting your model, they will be lazy loaded when referred.

OR

If Roles is not a navigation property then you can use

```
<td>
    @String.Join(", ", new userDbEntities()
        .roleTables.Where(rt => rt.Id == use.Roles).Select(r => r.NameOfRole))
</td>
```

But you should not be getting any data from repository/db when you are building your view, your Model should already contain everything you need to display.